# Incrementing one day to date in SQL Developer

Tags: sql, oracle, dateadd

```
data_var := dateadd(day,1,data_var);
```

I'm trying this to increment one day to data_var but I keep getting this error 'identifier 'dateadd' must be declared'. I searched all around and found nothing to help me deal with this issue. Help?

Comment: I'm not sure about  that edit @lucia; as I say the Oracle is a guess based on the error message. It's possible to connect to other RDBMS from SQL Developer.

Comment: True, I just assumed it because Oracle is probably the most used with SQL deleloper. But let's see what @André says.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By your mention of SQL Developer I'm going to assume you're using Oracle. If this is the case then the error makes complete sense as the function `DATEADD()` *does not exist*. It's always worth searching [the documentation](http://www.oracle.com/pls/db112/homepage) if you have a problem; in this instance you would have found nothing, which should have given you a clue.

To add a day to a date in Oracle simply add one to the date, i.e.:

```
date_var := date_var + 1;
```

For more information see [the documentation on datetime and interval arithmetic](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/sql_elements001.htm#SQLRF00208).